# Performance issues for 15.04

Tags: 15.04, dell, performance

I am using a Dell Vostro 270s machine. It was running on 14.04 and I upgraded to 15.04 recently.

64 Bit, 4 GB RAM

[image]

Most of the time switching between editor and browsers are horrible. It will be stuck for a while.

I am using atom editor and chromium as browser. Firefox is crashing often. I also switched from the default desktop to xfce4. Though it is not helping much. The network interface is also broken that cannot switch between the wired / wireless connections. See [earlier post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642853/dell-vostro-270-ethernet-in-ubuntu-14-10)

Let me know if you need anything more.

EDIT : Process List

[image]

Comment: Will there be anything related to data size increasing on hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably see your processes. 1.1GB swap is to much. Too much swap usage **will** cause slowness. Can you post a picture of the *Process* page so everyone may know the problem?

Comment: Here is the list https://gist.github.com/harikt/97151df53018441daeff

Comment: Sorry, but _github_ doesn't work well in China. Can you **edit** your post and add the picture? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. See image and you have a pastie : http://pastie.org/10363470

Comment: The problem may be this: **Chrome** and **Atom** are eating up about 1GB of your memory. I _recommend_ you to use **Firefox**, but I dont know why Firefox is crashing so often on your computer.